# Jest allow multi types for object structure match

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to create a test with `jest` which has to check if an object key is a `string` or a `number`.

Simple like this, but I cannot find anything in the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect).

*Test Example:*

```
test('Assets structure is right', () => {
    const assetExpectedStructure = {
      id: expect.any(String),
      source_type: expect.any(String),
      media_types: expect.any(Array),
      source_id: expect.any(String)   // <------------ HERE  String or Number
    }

    for (const asset of assets) {
        expect(asset).toMatchObject(assetExpectedStructure)
    }
 }
```

I could do `expect.anything()`, but this gets also other types  (Boolean, Objects etc.) which I don't want.

Does someone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with the library, but from the documentation, you can add your own matches:

```
expect.extend({
  toBeOneOf(received, constructors = [String, Number]) {
    const pass = !!constructors.find(c => received.constructor === c);
    if (pass) {
      return {
        message: () => `looks good`,
        pass: true,
      };
    } else {
      return {
        message: () => `no so good....`,
        pass: false,
      };
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Do you know where to put this to be global? I tried to place it in `./src/SetupTests.js`, but when I try to use it it does not find the new expect :-|

Comment: Unfortunately, can't say without knowing how your tests and files are structured. You'd want to do one of: 1) Put it as early as possible and export your extended library tools to each of your tests that use it rather than importing it independently each time. 2) Make sure you're modifying a shared global instance. All depends how your project is laid out.

Answer (score 1):

Without adding custom matchers via expect.extend, try:

```
test('Assets structure is right', () => {
    const assetExpectedStructure = {
      id: expect.any(String),
      source_type: expect.any(String),
      media_types: expect.any(Array),
      source_id: expect.stringMatching(/\d+/) // regex will match only alpha numerical string
    }

    for (const asset of assets) {
        expect(asset).toMatchObject(assetExpectedStructure)
    }
 }
```

Checkout https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectstringmatchingstring--regexp

Comment: As far as I know you cannot know the type with regexp, I was thinking about this to somehow use the `typeof` source_id, but I"m not sure how to do that, and by string matching directly there is no way you could now if is a string or a number type :-|

Comment: think of it like this> source_id can be 123 or '123'

Comment: @V.Sambor you can set /\d+/ as regex that will match only numerical strings, so 123 will be converted to '123' and will assert true (same for '123' string). Any other values will assert false

Comment: @V.Sambor other option is to try to create your own matcher via expect.extend

Comment: what if is undefined or null?

Comment: this /\d+/ should not match null and undefined